# writing .htaccess file 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess

comparisim
I need help writing my .htaccess. I have tried multiple different code snippets from around the web but to no avail. On the face of it, I think what I am trying to do should be quite simple. Basically I want to 301 redirect directories/folders of my site to the home page of the same site. Below is my current .htaccess code. As you can see; I have attempted to do this but it doesn’t work. Here is my site: [www.comparisim.co.uk](http://www.comparisim.co.uk/)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

   RewriteRule ^sim-only/* http://www.comparisim.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of redirecting. This is probably the quickest.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*/) http://www.comparisim.co.uk/
```

However I looked up your website and the only page that is indexed is your main page.
I would suggest creating a 404 page. You can also check [htaccess redirect](http://www.htaccessredirect.info/). They may have an example there.